# KendoUI grid databinding

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Can someone tell me how to bind kendo grid based on previous control selection?

Ex: I've placed one dropdown list and grid in a page. Now I wanted to populate data in grid based on dropdown selected value.

Can someone help me to do this. I'm working with MVC.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    $("#dept").kendoComboBox({
                filter: "contains",
                index: 0,
                dataTextField: "Name",
                dataValueField: "ID",
                dataSource: data,
                select: onSelect

            });
 //Dropdown change event
    function onSelect(e) {
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
        UpdateUPGridSource(dataItem.value);
    }
   //Refresh Datasource by Role wise
   function UpdateGridSource(DropdownValue) {
        var grd = $("#users").data("kendoGrid");
        //Set url property of the grid data source
        grd.dataSource.transport.options.read.url = '/Controller/JSONMethodName?ParameterName='+ RoleID;
        //Read data source to update
        grd.dataSource.read();
   }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.. I tried the same as you said. But after executing the method.. it is showing Do you want to open or save getdetails from localhost? along with Open, Save and Cancel buttons. Instead of binding the result values to grid.

Comment: function changedept() {
        var grd = $("#users").data("kendoGrid");
        var dropdownlist = $("#dept").data("kendoDropDownList");
        //Set url property of the grid data source
        grd.dataSource.transport.options.read.url = '/Home/GetUsersByDept?deptid=' + dropdownlist.value();
        //Read data source to update
        grd.dataSource.read();
}



public JsonResult GetUsersByDept(int deptid)
        {
  // here my dbfetch method
            return Json(emps, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Comment: Hi, I have changed my answer so Do try this.

Comment: I didnt see any difference :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this as follow:

```
$("#dept").kendoComboBox({
            filter: "contains",
            suggest: true,
            index: 0,
            dataTextField: "Name",
            dataValueField: "ID",
            dataSource: data,
            change: function(e){
                   grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({
                       field: "someField",
                       operator: "eq|etc.",
                       value: this.value()
                   });
            }
});
```

grid is the object you defined by kendoGrid() method.
hope it will help you.